# AWS EB Load Balancer SSL Certificate Page Not Loading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a public SSL certificate through AWS Certificate Manager and installed it on my EB Classic Load Balancer. The certificate was selectable from the load balancer's menu and the Certificate Manager now says it's "in use". So, I assume everything is set up correctly, but when I visit my site using https:// the page won't load. It just says waiting for ... until it ultimately gives up. Is there a time delay for this to enact or is there something more I need to do?

EDIT:
I appreciate the comments thus far, though I'm not sure how to redirect the traffic (kinda new to this). Here is a screenshot of my configuration. 
[image]

Comment: Are you able to load your page on `http://` ?

Comment: Yep, should’ve specified. Http:// works fine.

Comment: Waiting for what? And when it gives up, what error do you get? Check the targets on your load balancer, are they healthy?. Run tcpdump on your server, see if packets arrive on port 443 from the load balancer. If they do, check your web server's logs. If not, check network settings. Routing, Network ACL and Security Groups. The subnets that your load balancer is in must be allowed ro reach the web server. And the other way around in the case of Network ACL. Maybe allow everything both ways and if that works, then you know where the problem is and where to start fixing it.

Comment: Also, if the network connection works you should see ELB checks in your web server's logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to redirect traffic from 443 (AWS ELB) to your backend service.

The same listener that you have configured for http (port 80) > backend service.

443(https) > port
80(http) > port

**Edit:**

If you are using security groups, you will have to allow incoming traffic on port 443.

Comment: I see that incoming 443 is enabled for my security group. How do I do the redirect you refer to?

Comment: It looks like I have to use a VirtualHost config on Apache as Class Load Balancers don't support redirecting traffic. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Comment: I've added the VirtualHost redirect but now http just responds the same as https... it times out.